# Fixed html form input value that cannot be deleted

Tags: html, css

How can I make my input value permanent? I mean user can delete/change it.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<HTML>
<span>Mobile Number(Required)</span>
<input type ="integer" name="contact" id ="contact" value="+63" maxlength="13"/>
</HTML>
```

please help thanks a lot

Comment: Why not just prepend the value when handling the form data?

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript:

**[SEE FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vfag9drx/)**

```
 $('input.number').keyup(function(){
        if (
            ($(this).val().length > 0) && ($(this).val().substr(0,3) != '+63')
            || ($(this).val() == '')
            ){
            $(this).val('+63');    
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<span>Mobile Number(Required)</span>
<input type ="integer" class="number" name="contact" id ="contact" value="+63" maxlength="13"/>
```

Comment: where do i place those codes? do i need create a new <script> and paste it there?

Comment: @JuanCarlosDeLuna, place the codes on your javascript.. if you don't have yet created a javascript then create a tag for javascript then put the codes there.